# Angular data-binding stops working when array has duplicate values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this html that binds the $scope.comments array to an unordered list;

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="commentController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="c in comments">
            {{ c }}
        </li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

Then this script to initialise and add more items to the list;

```
<script>
    function commentController($scope){
        $scope.comments = ['Hi There.'];
        $scope.addComment = function(){
            $scope.comments.push($scope.newcomment);
            $scope.newcomment='';
        };
    };   
</script>
```

This works fine until i attempt to add a duplicate item. Debugging shows me that Javascript does push the duplicate item to the array, but angular databinding no longer updates the list.

Any idea why, or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="commentController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="c in comments track by $index">
            {{ c }}
        </li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

`track by $index` track the array element  by index not by value. see [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) in detai

Answer (score 1):

you need to track by index instead of values, so in ng-repeat editthis line

```
ng-repeat="c in comments track by $index"
```